# Does dynamic image loading decrease server overload?

Tags: javascript, performance

Example if I make a script that loads images only when user scrolls page to the location of where the image should be, would that script reduce page loading time and is it better in the long term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont decrease the time for the dom to become ready and displayed (at least not by much).  Images are loaded asynchronously by the browser and thus placeholders are put in place of images until they are fully loaded.

I would however suggest as you said implementing a script that loads images as they are needed, no point wasting peoples bandwidth with images that aren't needed. (If you have a lot of images), for example like google image search.

Bear in mind, if a user loads a page and scrolls down very quickly, a page that laods all images at once will have to wait for all images to load to guarantee the ones in view are displayed.  If you implement some sort of script you can control the way and order in which the images load.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will reduce the loading time, but you will make your users wait for images to load when they scroll down.

Comment: @IvanIvković it depends on so many factors, image size, number of images, number of connections the server and/or browser allows, connection speed of the user etc etc.

Comment: Aha, this case it's just few images (4-5) for a blogging site, mostly full width a little height (100px-200px) images.. The rest I don't know.

Comment: @IvanIvković if you only have 4 or 5 I wouldn't bother really, just load them all at once, you might see some advantage but I doubt it really.  If you had 10+ possibly even 15+ then id look at dunamically loading them when needed.  Best thing is to just try it out and see.